# What is the history of the "Jews for Jesus" movement?

Tags: messianic-judaism

I am aware that the whole concept of "Messianic Judaism" has existed since basically the dawn of Christian belief. My question specifically relates to the [Jews for Jesus](https://jewsforjesus.org/) movement. What is the history of this group and did they come from another group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the history of the "Jews for Jesus" movement?**

**Jews for Jesus** is an international Messianic Jewish movement founded in 1970.

> [**Jews for Jesus**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jews_for_Jesus) is an international Messianic Jewish non-profit organization headquartered in San Francisco, California. It was founded in 1970 by Moishe Rosen, as Hineni Ministries, before being incorporated under its current name in 1973. The group is known for its proselytism to Jews and promotes the belief that Jesus is the Christ and the Son of God.
>
> Despite its name, Jews for Jesus is not considered a Jewish organization by Rabbinic Jewish authorities, who view Jesus either as a good Jewish teacher or as a false prophet rather than a messianic figure.
>
> **History**
>
> **Jews for Jesus** was founded by Moishe Rosen, a Baptist minister of the Hebrew Christian movement who was previously a member of the American Board of Missions to the Jews (ABMJ). The organization was formed in 1970 under the name Hineni Ministries as a subsidiary group of the ABMJ. In 1973, Rosen left ABMJ and incorporated his ministry as a 501(c)3 nonprofit organization  under the name "Jews for Jesus." Originally, "Jews for Jesus" was simply one of the organization's several slogans, but after the media began to call the group "Jews for Jesus" the organization adopted that name.
>
> Rosen and followers began conducting community outreach on the streets and college campuses of San Francisco, California. In the following years, branches were established in New York, Chicago, and Boston. In 1978, the Jews for Jesus headquarters relocated to San Francisco, where it remains to this day. In 1981, the organization expanded internationally. According to **Jews for Jesus**, as of 2021 they have offices in 13 countries and 15 cities around the world.
>
> Rosen remained Executive Director until 1996, when he stepped down to work full-time as a staff missionary. He was replaced by David Brickner, who has held the position since. Rosen remained on its Board of Directors until his death in 2010.